# Volume of a sphere as a float

Tags: java

I get this error "error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float" for the volume.

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    float radius = keyboard.nextFloat();
    float area;
    float volume;

    area = (float)(4.0*Math.PI*radius*radius);
    volume = (float)(4.0 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
```

How can I get a float value for volume?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Math#pow` returns a `double`, you need to cast the whole expression to a `float` instead of just the first term.

```
volume = (float) ((4.0 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3));
```

Comment: Btw. `4.0` is also a `double`, if you would add an f `4.0f` then it would be a `float`.

Comment: @Ezsh You're welcome!  Please accept the answer if your problem is solved!